# double quote in form field value in wordpress plugin breaking codes

Tags: php, html, wordpress

In one of my made wordpress plugin, i created a admin page and have a form to save some option settings.In that form there are many fields like html - input, select....
one field is -

```
<input type="text" class="input-xlarge" name="token" value="<?php echo $token; ?>" id="token" />
```

problem is if admin enters some value in this field with quote mark(") then presses submit, option saved in db with various slashes(\) for some input like ', \ ,"..... but problem is if entered double quote("), which when form displayed with the new submitted value, form's html breaks as u imagine i am putting value of input under ""(value=""). 
So how do i do in wordpress plugin form in admin side to overcome this problem? 
I see there is a function "esc_attr_e" works too, what are the best wp functions available  to sort out the problem?

Comment: It is not a problem, slashes are used in javascript to create extra quotes or so.

Comment: nowhere is javascript in the form codes.as i said for the double quote entered form's html breaks in wordpress plugin admin page

Comment: What I meant was slashes are used to create quotes in most coding languages.

Comment: so then what i do to not break the html codes when there came double quote in input field value when the field value already under double quotes, in wp